# C++ interfaces: struct vs. class for interface/dependency injection

Tags: c++, class, struct, interface, pure-virtual

Going through a [blog](http://vladris.com/blog/2016/07/06/dependency-injection-in-c.html) about dependency injection. For the interface in their example, they use a `struct` with pure virtual methods instead of a `class`, and then inherit from the interface as a class.

```
struct IEngine
{
    virtual void Start() = 0;
    virtual void Stop() = 0;
    virtual ~IEngine() = default;
};

class V8Engine : public IEngine
{
    void Start() override { /* start the engine */ }
    void Stop() override { /* stop the engine */ }
};
```

My instinct would have been to make the `IEngine` interface a `class` instead. Is there a difference between using a `struct` vs `class` for the interface here? Would there be a situation where you would prefer to use one over the other?

Comment: I take it there is nothing special about using it for an interface?

Comment: `class` defaults to private, `struct` defaults to public; that's it.

Comment: Both keywords declare a class. The only technical difference is the default accessibility settings of the class. Any preference towards one of them would be purely conventional, not technical.

Comment: okay gotcha, thanks